# Excel VBA code working except one computer - Error 91

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel VBA sub that is used to search for contact details in Outlook.

The function is working on many computer except one that is the primary user of this function, on which it produces the error:

> `Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set`

Can someone help me please?

[image: img]

```
'Function to import Outlook contacts according to their client code
Sub ExportOutlookAddressBook()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olAL As Outlook.AddressList
    Dim olEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
    Dim CodeClient As String
    Dim RCompanyName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim AccountCount As Integer

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    CodeClient = 0
    RCompanyName = 0
    i = 0
    AccountCount = olNS.Accounts.Count
    Range("AA6:AF10").ClearContents
    For i = 1 To AccountCount
        Set olAL = olNS.AddressLists(i) 'Change name if different contacts list name
        Set olEntry = olAL.AddressEntries(1)
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("K6").Select
        CodeClient = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AA6").Select

        For Each olEntry In olAL.AddressEntries
            ' your looping code here
            RCompanyName = Left(Right(olEntry.GetContact.CompanyName, 7), 6)
            If RCompanyName = CodeClient Then
            ActiveCell.Value = olEntry.GetContact.FullName
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = olEntry.GetContact.BusinessTelephoneNumber 'business phone number
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = olEntry.Address 'email address
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = olEntry.GetContact.CompanyName
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = olEntry.GetContact.BusinessAddress
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        Next olEntry
    Next i

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olAL = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("K7").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of  `olEntry.GetContact.CompanyName` when the code stops?  You should be able to hover your mouse over that part of the code to see the value, or else try `MsgBox olEntry.GetContact.CompanyName` on the line before the error.  I'm thinking that contact doesn't have a "Company Name" set.

Comment: What are the language settings (locale) on both PCs?

Comment: @Dominique - If Outlook wasn't installed, the code wouldn't have made it past the second line.  :-)   ...but the locale is a good point... Are any of these computers setup in different primary languages? (ie., https://superuser.com/q/709043/774713)

Comment: Different version of Outlook maybe?  Saying that though - it would fall at first hurdle as well as the reference would be missing.

Comment: [AddressEntry.GetContact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getcontact) returns `Nothing` if it isn't in the address book.

Comment: @Comintern - ...and therefore `Left` and `Right` would produce an error #91.

Comment: @ashleedawg Right. All this code should need is an `Is Nothing` check before trying to use the return value from `olEntry.GetContact`.

Comment: @ashleedawg I try your code but I got an incompatibility error on line `If Not olEntry.GetContact.CompanyName Is Nothing Then` and the CompanyName is highlighted. This error is happening on my computer when the previous code was working

Comment: I succeed to make it work with my computer using this ` If Not olEntry.GetContact.CompanyName = "" Then` but I still got the error 91 on the other computer at the same place

Comment: Can you remove the Left and Right function to test it and see if the problem occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Besides adding the `If Nothing...`'s, I tidied some of the other repetative code.

```
Option Explicit  'this line is recommended at the very top of every module.


'Function to import Outlook contacts according to their client code
Sub ExportOutlookAddressBook()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, olNS As Outlook.Namespace, olAL As Outlook.AddressList
    Dim olEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry, CodeClient As String, RCompanyName As String, i As Long
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("AA6:AF10").ClearContents

    For i = 1 To olNS.Accounts.Count
        Set olAL = olNS.AddressLists(i) 'Change name if different contacts list name
        Set olEntry = olAL.AddressEntries(1)
        CodeClient = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("K6")
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AA6").Select

        For Each olEntry In olAL.AddressEntries
            ' your looping code here
            RCompanyName = Left(Right(olEntry.GetContact.CompanyName, 7), 6)
            If RCompanyName = CodeClient Then
                With ActiveCell
                    .Value = olEntry.GetContact.FullName
                    .Offset(0, 1) = olEntry.GetContact.BusinessTelephoneNumber 'business phone number
                    .Offset(0, 2) = olEntry.Address 'email address
                    If Not olEntry.GetContact Is Nothing Then
                        If Not olEntry.GetContact.CompanyName Is Nothing Then
                            .Offset(0, 3) = olEntry.GetContact.CompanyName
                        End If
                        If Not olEntry.GetContact.BusinessAddress Is Nothing Then
                            .Offset(0, 4) = olEntry.GetContact.BusinessAddress
                        End If
                    End If
                    .Offset(1, 0).Select
                End With
            End If
        Next olEntry
    Next i

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olAL = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("K7").Select
End Sub
```